# TransformContext missing odata parameters after upgrading from 2013 to Web 8.5 - RSTL implementation

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8.5, odata, tcdl

In the process of upgrading Tridion from `2013SP1` to `Web 8.5` with the RSTL tag library we are observing missing odata parameters (parameters passed into oData API) while the `RSTL` start tag method is called (`TransformContext` object). 
Both method calls `tagContext.getRenderParameters()` and `tagContext.getGlobalContext()` are resulting only in one parameter key of `$expand` with empty value.
Since `RSTL` was last updated by Mihai to support 2013 (not 8.5) we worked with SDL services to map the SDL API calls from 2013 to 8.5. Largely the `RSTL` library is now working with the exception of this issue. The tag class with start tag method in question implements `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` in `cd_dynamic-8.5.0-1062.jar`

Comment: One further question, is there anything within the odata configuration or component that could be the cause ?

Comment: Could you clarify which parameters are missing?

Comment: Turned out to be a defect in the 8.5 library. SDL has since patched the issue.